# How to write a Mixin for checking if the logged user has access to certain model instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to write a Mixin (or use a third-party one) for checking if the logged user is the owner of certain object.

```
url(r'^api/mymodel/(?P<pk>\d)/?', CreateUpdateMyModel.as_view(), name='create_or_update')


class MyModel(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField('auth.User')


class OwnerRequired(SingleObjectMixin):
    # do this self.object = self.get_object() for getting the object 
    # 

    # some logic for checking if request.user == self.object.owner
    # otherwise return something like Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

Inheriting from `SingleObjectMixin` is important to me, since I want to be able to do something like:

```
class CreateUpdateMyModel(APIView, OwnerRequired):

    model = MyModel

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # self.object should be available here
        # so that write some code taking it into account
```

How `OwnerRequired` should look for fulfilling this?

I'm open to another alternatives, in fact, I've checked [`PermissionRequiredMixin`](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/v1.4.0/access.html#permissionrequiredmixin) from django-braces and I'd like to use it, but I'm not sure how to do it

```
 permission_required = ??  # I can code a method for, but how can I pass the model instance and the request.user?
```

Is there another simple alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [object level permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions#object-level-permissions).  There's also a relevant example on that page in the examples sections - see the [IsOwnerOrReadOnly example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions#examples).

Also note that object level permissions are only run either:

- You are using the `GenericAPIView` or a subclass of it, and calling `get_object()` to retrieve the instance.
- You explicitly call `self.check_object_permissions(request, instance` within your view code.